# How to map List c# --> proto3

Tags: c#, list, automapper, grpc, proto

How can I map List of object  from c# to message repeated from proto3 using AutoMapper?

```
var list = new List<Model>()
{
new Model() {Id = 1, Name = 
"something"}
};

cfg.CreateMap<ProtoList, List<Model>>().ReverseMap();
```

Proto:

```
message ProtoList{
repeated ProtoModel Model = 1;
}
```

I tried [Serializing/Deserializing Protocol Buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400459/serializing-deserializing-protocol-buffers)
But this is not working for me

Comment: Is it similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745327/automapper-ienumerable-within-class-is-not-being-mapped-to-repeatedfield/56745583#56745583)?

Comment: Ok it works! Thank you John

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning to get to having a look at your specific question but today has been a busy day :-D I'm glad it could help you.